# Converting hexadecimal number to decimal using Linux terminal

Tags: terminal, hex, syntax-error, decimal, echo

When I type in the shell ->

```
$echo $(( 16#FF ))
```

The output is "255" which is the decimal conversion of the hexadecimal number "0xFF"

But when I try to convert the number "FF" to another base similarly:

```
$ echo $(( ffb5cd10#FF ))
```

I get the following error:

```
"bash: ffb5cd10#FF : syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "#FF ")"
```

Comment: 255 is not the decimal equivalent of 0x16. It's 0xFF. You have the syntax backwards. The 16 means base 16 (hexadecimal).

Comment: 1Thanks, my bad..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the correct syntax of this command is $echo $ (('base'#number )) where base is actually the base of the number you have given to the shell and it will give you the decimal conversion. Here, FF is the number and 16 is the base and FF converts to 255..

Comment: It looks like this only works for hexadecimal numbers which are less than or equal to decimal 9,999,999,999,999,999,999 (= 10,000,000,000,000,000,000 - 1 = 10 billion billion - 1). 484867784a5845516146550a base 16 to base 10 = 22370451988863230639950157066 = true and $ echo $((16#484867784a5845516146550a)) = 5357107972583871754 = false. echo $((16#550a)) = 21770 = true.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

"(error token is "#FF ")"

you put a number in hex format and ask to return a hex again.

the sintax for this, (i think) can return the expected result if you ommit the base from the code, like this:

$ echo $(( ffb5cd10# ))